# How should I architect out a React project where a component is rendered differently every time?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I have a component that relies on a few AJAX calls to finish rendering. The AJAX calls return something different every time.  I want to have a button that will re-render the random component every time.
Right now, I have two components, `Random` and `Next`.

`Next` currently renders itself like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Random variable={this.getVariable()}></Random>
      <button>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and `Random` renders itself like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="clue-module col-md-4">
      <div>{this.props.variable}</div>
      {this.renderTags()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

So the way I have it right now is that in `Next`, I make an AJAX call that gets response that's returned by `this.getVariable()`. It's then passed into `Random`.  `Random` makes an AJAX call that uses the value of `this.props.variable` as a request parameter.  In its `render`, it displays the value of `this.props.variable` as well as `this.renderTags()`, which is the result of that second AJAX call.

Right now this isn't working properly.  The AJAX calls are successful, but not together.  I think it's because `Next` is rendered before the request is complete, and then `Random` isn't properly rendering because it's not getting the results of the `Next` AJAX call in time.

How should I architect this out?  Should all of the requests go in `Random`?  How would I then set up `Next` so it renders a new `Random` every time I hit the button?

Comment: Can you show the components as a whole rather than just the render functions?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a state variable in the parent and passing the ajax to that. Usually in componentDidMount().

```js
componentDidMount() { this.setState({variable: this.getVariable}); }
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Random variable={this.state.variable}></Random>
      <button>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a Flux-like architecture before your code becomes spaghetti but basically you want the **state** of Next to change every time you get a new Value.

So, in the callback your Ajax call, perform a call to `this.setState({theVar: theValue} )`

Calling `setState()` will trigger a render of `Next`

The `render()` method of Next becomes

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Random variable={this.state.theVar}></Random>
      <button>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Edit**
For the sake of completeness, triggering a change of State in the *parent* of Next and passing the value through the props of Next would achieve the same result. That is the idea behind the concept of 'controller view' in Flux (modulo the store)

Comment: What should I do to solve the problem of the component rendering before the AJAX request is completed?